# Using indexes correctly in SQL query

Tags: php, sql, indexing

I'm kind of new to using SQL and I am trying to run a query comparing two values in two separate tables.  I have indexed the columns that are being used, but I am not entirely sure how indexing works. I am embedding it in PHP and it currently is taking a long time (sometimes even timing out) when I try to run the query.  The two tables have about 250k rows in each so it shouldn't be too big of a query.  Here is my code:

```
$users1 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT idtracker.uuid
  FROM idtracker, download_tracker 
  WHERE idtracker.uuid = download_tracker.pluginId
  && idtracker.date > (NOW() - (2000000))", $con));
```

I am not sure if it is very efficient comparing two rows directly like I am doing here.  If I could just get some insight on what I could do to improve the speed of this query it would be very helpful.

Thanks
-Ryan

Comment: Have you tried using a join yet?

Answer (score 1):

Before you can do any real testing / optimizing, you need to fix the query:

```
idtracker.date > (NOW() - (2000000))
```

is wrong.

If your `idtracker.date` is of type `DATE` or `DATETIME` and you want to compare it to another date (`NOW()` minus something), you need to use the mysql [`DATE_ADD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function or something similar.

Comment: My date field is currently the timestamp type as of now.  I was looking online and it seemed that everyone using DATE_ADD was using it with either the DATE or DATETIME types.  The query using the TIMESTAMP type works the way I want it to for the job I'm doing so would it be more effeceint/worthwhile to change the type to DATE or DATETIME?

Comment: @Raj3m8 No, TIMESTAMP, is fine, but you can't just substract an integer from it, you need to use de mysql date/time functions.